# POSTGIS SELECT optmization

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.1

I have a query that works, but wondering if there is a faster less obtuse form that I can use.  I have already created a bounding box around my geometry to narrow the search, but the multiple calls to ST_Transforms seems awkward.  BTW:  the two lines (gg and gm) have identical points.

Thanks in advance,
-Matt

```
CREATE TABLE lines
(
  line_id bigserial NOT NULL,
  line_gm_bbox geometry,
  line_gm_line geometry,
  line_gg_line geography(LineString,4326),
)
WITH ( OIDS=FALSE );

CREATE INDEX line_bbox_idx
  ON lines
  USING gist
  (line_gm_bbox );


SELECT l.* FROM lines AS l WHERE l.line_gm_bbox && ST_Transform( ST_Buffer( ST_Transform( ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-71.44513306666667 42.7368536)',4326),3395 ), 2000 ), 4326 ) 
                             AND ST_DWithin( l.line_gg_line, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-71.44513306666667 42.7368536)',4326), 200);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `ST_Buffer` in `WHERE` is expensive, since it would need to buffer *all* of your geometries before filtering. Use only `ST_DWithin` for the same effect.

Furthermore, the `lines` table schema is *overkill*. You only need one geography column, which does not need to be transformed to query metric distances. The bounding boxes should technically stored in the gist index, but can otherwise be extracted into a [box type](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/reference.html#PostGIS_Types), if you needed it for some purpose. Most of the time you don't need to care though, as long as the gist index is there.

Redefine the `lines` table to a simpler schema:

```
CREATE TABLE lines
(
  gid bigserial primary key,
  geog geography(LineString,4326)
);
CREATE INDEX ON lines USING gist (geog);
```

If you are trying to query all the lines within 200 m of the point-of-interest, simplify the query as:

```
SELECT l.*
FROM lines AS l
WHERE ST_DWithin(l.geog, ST_MakePoint(-71.44513306666667, 42.7368536), 200);
```